# Building backbone application with GULP

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gulp

When I run `gulp` after `npm install` and `bower install` the application runs fine on my localhost. However when I open the static HTML files from the build folder they don't render correctly.

Comment: Define "don't render correctly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve the files so that they are hosted by your localhost on a port. One of the easier ways to do this would be to use python simple server.

Run the command below from the directory with your static HTML files. When you have a simple server running they can pull the right resources from other files they need to render correctly:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

Comment: This works perfectly! Would the same principal apply if I drop the HTML into a Flask app and serve the templates from Flask.

Comment: To clarify, if you use simple server with the html files in your Flask app, your HTML templates will render but they won't load data dynamically unless you're also running your Flask server to handle route requests.